# Pass Args to generate

Tags: haskell, random, quickcheck, deterministic

Does QuickCheck have a way to pass an Args object (or at least specify the seed) to the generate `(:: Gen a -> IO a)` function (or something equivalent)?
I see that it has `quickCheckWith` which takes an Args, but it can only return a Result.  There doesn't seem to be a `generateWith` function.

Comment: `Gen` couldn't do anything with an `Args`. You can specify the seed manually by simply deconstructing the `Gen` datatype by pattern matching or using `unGen`.

Comment: I tried that.  unGen isn't visible (is it?)

Comment: You need to import Test.QuickCheck.Gen.